# Match single word length between spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

On a text, I need to match single words with the same length, in order to fill an array. The words could be made of non-word characters and number, but not spaces.

For example, this string:
    `A string with a number 100%, and a website www.mysite.org.`

using this syntax
    `\s[\w\d\W]{6}(?= )`

at length of 6, it founds 3 matches but including **_with_a** which is made of two words (I use underscore to mark the whitespaces). Instead the result should be only **string**, and **number**.

Consider that the length number **will be increased** in a loop in order to catch all text but spaces, and then fill the array.

So, the resulting matches for the previous string, should be:

> `at` 1 `should match:` A a a
>   `at` 3 `should match:` and
>   `at` 4 `should match:` with
>   `at` 5 `should match:` 100%,
>   `at` 6 `should match:` string number
>   `at` 7 `should match:` website
>   `at` 15 `should match:` www.mysite.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:^| )(\S{3})(?= |$)
```

and grab matched group #1.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bL4eW2/3)

Comment: I'm sorry, you have been very fast. I added more details. The words could be made of non-word characters and number, but not spaces, and the length number is incremental.

Comment: Did you check demo link. `\S{6}` matches 6 non space characters only including word and non-word characters.

Comment: Yes, but for example at 3 it matches also **org** which should be considered part of the word _www.mysite.org_
At 2 it matches **%,** which should be considered part of _100%,_

Comment: I have seen your updated question. And I have also tested my regex in the demo link by changing numbers after `\S` and all of them are working as per your expected results.

Comment: Ah I see your point. Check my edited answer now. Matched group is in `MATCH INFORMATION` on right-bottom.